# How to retrieve editText values and add it in a List<String>?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, android-recyclerview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4R4b.png)AddMeetingActivity

```
 @BindView(R.id.my_toolbar2)
Toolbar   mToolbar;
@BindView(R.id.in_time)
EditText txtTime;
@BindView(R.id.in_place)
EditText txtPlace;
@BindView(R.id.in_comment)
EditText txtComment;
@BindView(R.id.participant)
EditText txtParticipant;
@BindView(R.id.participant2)
EditText txtParticipant2;
@BindView(R.id.participant3)
EditText txtParticipant3;
@BindView(R.id.participant4)
EditText txtParticipant4;

 @OnClick(R.id.create)
void addMeeting(){
    Meeting meeting = new Meeting(System.currentTimeMillis(),
            txtTime.getText().toString(),
            txtPlace.getText().toString(),
            txtComment.getText().toString(),

    );
    mApiService.createMeeting(meeting);
    finish();
}
```

I want to add the string value of 4 four EditText in one arraylist, these EditText is where I type Names of participants. Then I have to send the new list in addmeeting() method but I can not find how to do it.

```
public abstract class DummyMeetingGenerator {

public static List<String> participants = Arrays.asList(
        "nouveau@gmail.com, ancien@gmail.com, super@gmail.com, nul@gmail.com");

public static List<Meeting> DUMMY_MEETINGS = Arrays.asList(
        new Meeting(1, "14:00", "Room A", " Future Project ", participants ));

static List<Meeting> generateMeetings() {
    return new ArrayList<>(DUMMY_MEETINGS);
}
```

This is for you to see more clearly what I am trying to do, I enter the mails of participants in 4 edittext and when i click on create button it supposed to display the mails i entered in an arraylist to the recyclerview textview. How can I do it ?

If you need more precison let me know. Thanks

[image]

Comment: first of all can you provide an outline of your Message class, second what does this have to do with an arraylist. You are already setting the text of three endittext fields into your meetings object. You create a list in generateMeetings, but it already has one meeting assigned to it, since you copied DUMMY_MEETINGS into it. So what are you trying to do here. Also you are talking about displaying it in a recyclerview. Which has nothing to do with the code you presenting here

Comment: I'm really confused, to what you want us to do

Comment: What should happen in which method and please attch the classes you want to use, so that we know which methods and fields are accessible (e.g. the Message class)

Comment: Use an `ArrayList` and `arrayList.add( item )`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yeah, but he was also talking about sending data and using the recycler view

Comment: @IntoVoid  I want to know how to send the e-mails written in 4 separate EditText in my AddMeetingAcivity to an only one TextView who is present in my recyclerview.

Comment: @IntoVoid The recyclerView is displayed in other activity called "MainActivity"

Comment: @IntoVoid and the e-mails should be in a List<String> like in the second part of code

Comment: @IntoVoid I edit the question with sreenshots

Comment: @Hwoarang54 you mean like this (down below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um you mean like this?:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(4);
list.add(txtParticipant.getText().toString());
list.add(txtParticipant2.getText().toString());
list.add(txtParticipant3.getText().toString());
list.add(txtParticipant4.getText().toString());
```

or like this (there are many ways to put stuff in a list):

```
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(
        txtParticipant.getText().toString(),
        txtParticipant2.getText().toString(),
        txtParticipant3.getText().toString(),
        txtParticipant4.getText().toString()
));
```

Comment: Yes it works! Thank you, it may be simple but i'm beginner